# General Search with array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch

Anyone knows if it is possible to do the following search in elasticsearch without using scripts.

Any suggestion it is welcome, as I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "brands.*.shirts.colors": "red"
    }
  }
}
```

**brands:** arrays of objects of brand

***:** any object of brand object

**colors:** array of colors

ps: the structure is merely illustrative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improving the answer of Val I got the code that works.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["brands.*.shirts.colors"],
      "query": "red"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `query_string` like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "brands.\*.shirts.colors:red"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't work but looking in the documentation more about the query_string I found the solutions. Thank you for the guidance.